# CIFS (Windows Share) or NFS for Windows directory share

Tags: windows, linux, network-shares, nfs, cifs

I have a (Virtualized) Linux server which I'd like to backup regularly. The rest of our environment is Microsoft and our backup solution (ArchiveIQ) runs only on Windows - there are no Linux clients.

My solution is to backup the pertinent data to a Windows share which will, in turn, be caught up in the nightly ArchiveIQ backup schedule. Where I need advice is how to go about doing this.

One recommendation was to create an NFS share on a Windows machine and then mount that on the Linux machine. I have very little experience with NFS and am having trouble mounting the share onto the directory.

What I do have experience with is Samba. Would there be any pitfalls of blowing away the NFS share and recreating it as a Windows share and then just mounting with CIFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the exact same thing for backing up data to a Lacie NAS through CIFS.  Works flawlessly.

1. Mount the share with mount.cifs
2. Check it mounted OK
3. Copy the data (I use rsync)
4. Unmount the share
5. Check it unmounted OK

As simple as that.

Comment: Thanks Matt. That's what I was thinking. I was wondering, though, why you unmount and then remount instead of just keeping it mounted?

Comment: That way you guarantee that it is mounted every time and not some leftover stale mount from a while back that is no longer linked to the share.

Comment: `cifs` handles reconnecting quite well, according to my tests.